# how to send Whatsapp chat as a file using Windows Phone?

Tags: whatsapp

Please inform how can I send a WhatsApp conversation to any email address on my Nokia Lumia 535?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the chat you wish to export.
2. Tap the three dots in the bottom right hand corner > info or group info.
3. Tap the three dots in the bottom right hand corner > email chat history.

Note: You may not be able to email your entire chat history due to Windows Mail size restrictions.

Reference: [How do I save my chat history?](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/22548236)